# Predict price range of houses

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification, regression

I have a dataset with several features of houses including type, location, the number of bedrooms, etc. For example:

- Type: Apartment, Semi-detached House, Single-detached House
- Location: (Lat, Lon) Pairs like (40.7128° N, 74.0059° W)
- Number of Bedrooms: 1, 2, 3, 4 ...

The target variable I want to predict is the house price. However, the house price given in the original dataset is the intervals of prices instead of numeric values, for example:

- House Price: [0,100000), [100000,150000), [150000,200000), [200000,250000), etc.

So my question is what model should I use if I want to predict the range of house price? Simple regression models seem not work because we are predicting intervals instead of continuous numeric values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the median of the price range and run a linear regression. In your case the labels would be {50000, 125000, 175000, 225000, ...}. After you get the predicted price just pick the range it falls into.

Alternatively, if the price ranges are fixed, you can use a one-vs-all logistic regression, although I am sure this is not the best approach.